# Nested ManyToMany Field in Django

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-admin

Using: Django 1.8 and Python 3.4

I have the following model:

```
class SpaCenter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    faq = models.ManyToManyField(SpaCenterFAQ)


class SpaCenterFAQ(models.Model):
    pass


class SpaCenterFAQLanguage(models.Model):
    faq = models.ForeignKey(SpaCenterFAQ)
    faq_language = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                        choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                        default=ENGLISH)
    faq_question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    faq_answer = models.TextField()
```

To summarise:

- Each SpaCenter can have multipe FAQs
- Each FAQ can belong to multiple Spa Centers
- Each FAQ needs to be in multiple languages so the SpaCenterFAQLanguage model deals with language translations

Using the Django built-in admin interface I would like to be able to input all the different translations for the FAQs while being in the SpaCenter admin interface.

So essentially this is a nested relationship and I am aware of this thread:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025

As well as both of these community built apps which attempt to deal with the issue:

- [djangosuperlines](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-super-inlines/)
- [djangonestedlines](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline)

However, I am still struggling to understand how to define this in the Django Admin even when using those libraries.

Need help in understanding how this kind of relationship can be displayed in the admin interface of the SpaCenter.

Many thanks.

EDIT:

- The SpaCenterFAQ model has no fields because of the separate table for handling languages. Example: There can be a few FAQs for one spacenter. However, each of the FAQs needs to be in multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

using djangosuperlines it should look like:

```
from django.contrib.admin import TabularInline, StackedInline, site
from super_inlines.admin import SuperInlineModelAdmin, SuperModelAdmin

from .models import *


class SpaCenterFAQLanguageInlineAdmin(SuperInlineModelAdmin, TabularInline):
    model = SpaCenterFAQLanguage


class SpaCenterFAQInlineAdmin(SuperInlineModelAdmin, StackedInline):
    model = SpaCenter
    inlines = (SpaCenterFAQLanguageInlineAdmin,)


class SpaCenterAdmin(SuperModelAdmin):
    inlines = (SpaCenterFAQInlineAdmin,)


site.register(SpaCenter, SpaCenterAdmin)
```

Comment: Sorry, jumpted to conclusion too early - this worked for another part of my models where there were 2 foreign key relationships. So if a SpaCenter could have multiple FAQs but each FAQ could only have 1 spa center - then your code holds the truth. 

However, the problem here is the Many-to-Many so I am assuming somewhere there must be a .through argument

Comment: model = SpaCenter.faq.through

Comment: actually, you can't edit many-to-many in inline, when you add spa center - your either choose existing faq with many-to-many field, or add a new one, and edit it in popup window.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

class SpaCenter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    faqs = models.ManyToManyField('SpaCenterFAQ', blank=True)


class SpaCenterFAQ(models.Model):
    spa_centers = models.ManyToManyField('SpaCenter', blank=True)

class SpaCenterFAQLanguage(models.Model):
    ENGLISH = '1'
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = ((ENGLISH, 'english'),)

    faq = models.ForeignKey(SpaCenterFAQ)
    faq_question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    faq_answer = models.TextField()
    faq_language = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                        choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                        default=ENGLISH


from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *


class SpaCenterFAQLanguageInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SpaCenterFAQLanguage

class SpaCenterFaqAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = SpaCenterFAQLanguageInlineAdmin,


class SpaCenterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(SpaCenter, SpaCenterAdmin)
admin.site.register(SpaCenterFAQ, SpaCenterFaqAdmin)
```